# Picture Control background is gray and I want it white

Tags: image, visual-c++, mfc, background-color, picturebox

My application has a picture control, whose background is gray and I want it to be white. I already tried several things, like: derive a class and override `OnPaint` method; respond to `WM_CTLCOLOR` message (adding `ON_WM_CTLCOLOR()`and processing it), but no success.

Entry on Message map:

```
ON_WM_CTLCOLOR()
```

Implementation:

```
BOOL CMyDialog::OnInitDialog()
{
    __super::OnInitDialog();

    white.CreateSolidBrush(RGB(255,255,255));

    //...

    return TRUE;  // return TRUE  unless you set the focus to a control
}


HBRUSH CMyDialog::OnCtlColor(CDC* pDC, CWnd* pWnd, UINT nCtlColor)
{
    if (pWnd == GetDlgItem(IDC_PICTURE))
    {
        return white;
    }

    return __super::OnCtlColor(pDC, pWnd, nCtlColor);
}
```

Header file class definition:

```
CBrush white;

HBRUSH OnCtlColor(CDC* pDC, CWnd* pWnd, UINT nCtlColor);
```

[image: gray back]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After some debugging using Spy++, I've realized the Picture Control is a Static Control and the message I have to process is not `WM_CTLCOLOR` but `WM_CTLCOLORSTATIC`

[image]

So, on the dialog that contains it I changed the message map from

```
ON_WM_CTLCOLOR()
```

to

```
ON_MESSAGE(WM_CTLCOLORSTATIC, OnCtlColorStatic)
```

---

On the implementation, change the method from

```
HBRUSH CMyDialog::OnCtlColor(CDC* pDC, CWnd* pWnd, UINT nCtlColor)
{
    if (pWnd == GetDlgItem(IDC_PICTURE))
    {
        return white;
    }

    return __super::OnCtlColor(pDC, pWnd, nCtlColor);
}
```

to

```
LRESULT CMyDialog::OnCtlColorStatic(WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    HWND hWnd = (HWND)lParam;

    if (::GetDlgCtrlID(hWnd) == IDC_PICTURE)
        return (LRESULT)white.GetSafeHandle();

    return DefWindowProc(WM_CTLCOLORSTATIC, wParam, lParam);
}
```

---

And in the header file, change also the method from

```
HBRUSH OnCtlColor(CDC* pDC, CWnd* pWnd, UINT nCtlColor);
```

to

```
LRESULT OnCtlColorStatic(WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);
```

---

Notice a subtle difference: the old one worked by returning the **HBRUSH** brush handle directly; the new one expects a function returning a **LRESULT** typed variable, so the cast.

The result is what I was expecting:

[image]

***UPDATE***: I recently needed to do a thing where I had to set the Text Color of a Static and discovered that I can get its device context also:

```
HDC hDC= (HDC)wParam;
HWND hWnd = (HWND)lParam;
```

So, after I could easily do it by:

```
SetBkMode(hDC, TRANSPARENT);
SetTextColor(hDC, RGB(0,127,127));
```