# How to change background color in static text visual studio?

Tags: visual-c++, mfc, bcg

I am trying to change background color of static text in our project. We use BCG library also.

In h. file I have

```
afx_msg HBRUSH CtlColor(CDC * pDC, CWnd * pWnd, UINT nCtlColor);
COLORREF m_bckNewsClr;
```

In cpp. I have:

```
m_bckNewsClr = RGB(255, 255, 255);

HBRUSH CStartPage::CtlColor(CDC * pDC, CWnd * pWnd, UINT nCtlColor)
{
    pWnd->GetDlgItem(IDC_STATIC_NEWS_CAPTION_1);
    pDC->SetBkColor(m_bckNewsClr);
    return (HBRUSH)m_Brush.GetSafeHandle();
}
```

In massage map:

```
ON_WM_CTLCOLOR()
```

Anyway, it is even not visible the function CtlColor, when I put the breakpoint.

Does someone know how to change this backgound static text in this case?

Comment: You can use Spy++ (if x64 target platform: Spy++ 64) to discover if the message is really `WM_CTLCOLOR` . I suspect in the specific case is `WM_CTLCOLORSTATIC` . Some more guidance on https://stackoverflow.com/a/43120662/383779

Comment: `ON_WM_CTLCOLOR` redirects the message to **On**CtlColor

Answer (score 3):

The `ON_WM_CTLCOLOR` expects a method named:

```
afx_msg HBRUSH OnCtlColor(
   CDC* pDC,
   CWnd* pWnd,
   UINT nCtlColor 
);
```

See also [CWnd::OnCtlColor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0wwk06hc.aspx) for a sample how to do it.

And also https://stackoverflow.com/a/12007350/8918119